# sscanf to array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to use sscanf to copy a line of formatted text into an array of structs.

Now this works perfectly, but I end up getting this warning:

Format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'unsigned char **'.

These are the typedefs I want to use:

```
 typedef unsigned char* command_t;
 typedef struct {
    command_t command;
    int p1;
    int p2;
} parameters_t;
```

And this is the relevant part of the code:

```
    paramters_t parameters[100];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) {
      sscanf(line, "%s %d %d",&parameters[i].command,&parameters[i].p1,&parameters[i].p2);
      i++;
    }
```

So how come &parameters[i].command is a double pointer?
Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could do with checking the return value from `sscanf`

Comment: `sscanf`returns the right number of words for each line, but you're right, I should still check. But still, why is &parameters[i].command of type 'unsigned char **'. Where did the second pointer come from?

Comment: If I use `parameters[i].command` without the & the program crashes during sscanf after compiling.

Comment: Argument 3 is not `%s`, it is `%d`. Did you post the question right? You say it works perfectly, but "ends up with" that, but it's compiler warning, surely? So why run the code?

Comment: Yes, I did post the question right. I get the same warning for argument 2, which actually is `%d` as well. So I have to allocate memory for each pointer in the array? How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see couple of errors with the program -- one syntactic and one semantic.

The syntax error can be fixed by using:

```
sscanf(line, "%s %d %d", parameters[i].command, &parameters[i].p1, &parameters[i].p2);
//                      ^^ Remove the &
```

However, the greater problem is that you haven't allocated any memory for `parameters[i].command` before reading data into it.

There are couple of ways to solve the problem.

1. Make command a fixed size array.
2. Allocate memory for command by using `malloc`.

If you are going to use some hard coded number for the size of the array, I suggest using the first approach. Then, you don't have to worry about memory allocation and deallcation.

Change

```
typedef unsigned char* command_t;
```

to

```
typedef unsigned char command_t[100]; // Make it large enough for your need.
```

Make sure to prevent reading into command more characters that it can hold.

```
sscanf(line, "%99s %d %d", parameters[i].command, &parameters[i].p1, &parameters[i].p2);
//             ^^ Specify the maximum number of characters to read
```

Comment: Perhaps change the format string in the `sscanf` so that the buffer does not overrun

Comment: Thank you for your long post. This is a project I share with two other guys and sadly I can't change the type of command_t. Also command_t is guaranteed to be between 2 - max. 30 characters. If I wanted to use your second approach and use `malloc`, where would I have to allocate the memory for `parameters[i].command`? Before sscanf?

Comment: Okay, so I tried the following:                                                                `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) {
    parameters[i].befehl = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
    sscanf(line, "%s %d %d",parameters[i].befehl,&parameters[i].p1,&parameters[i].p2);
    i++;
    printf("\n %s", parameters[i].befehl);
    }`                                                                                                                 But sscanf still crashes. Where did I go wrong? Do I have to allocate memory for the whole array?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(unsigned char))` allocates memory to hold only one character. Use something like `malloc(100)`.

Comment: Damn, this did it. Didn't think far enough, thank you so much :)

Comment: And the technique not to overrun the buffer and do not to use `free` somewhere down the line

Comment: If you're using POSIX 2008 or later, you can use the `m` modifer to get scanf to malloc the memory for you: `sscanf(line, "%ms%d%d", &parameters[i].command,`...  In this case you want the `&` as scanf expects a pointer to a pointer.